# Ideas to solve the following system of equations

Tags: derivatives, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative

I am trying to solve an exercise with partial derivatives. I have no issue with the derivation part, but once you do that you are supposed to solve a system of equations to find the solution. I already did a few exercises of this kind. However, I found one with a particular system of equations that I can not figure out how to solve. Multiplying one equation by something to delete one variable and solve the other one does not seem to work. I need to know the value of $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$.

Said system of equations is:

$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
\left(2x+y\right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+x\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=-2 \\ 
y\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\left(x-2y\right)\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=-1 \\ 
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$

The answers are supposed to be:
$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}=\frac{4y-x}{2\left(x^2-2xy-y^2\right)}$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=\frac{y-2x}{2\left(x^2-2xy-y^2\right)}$

Comment: think about $v=xy$.

Comment: Can you show your work, even if you don't think it worked? This is just solving two equations in two unknowns, $\partial{x}/\partial{u}$ and $\partial{y}/\partial{u}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system of equations can be written as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2x+y & x \\
y & x-2y \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Using the formula for the inverse of a $2\times 2$ matrix, we get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{(2x+y)(x-2y)-yx}
\begin{pmatrix}
x-2y & -x \\
-y & 2x+y \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}
\\
= 
\frac{1}{2x^2-4xy-2y^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
(x-2y)(-2) + (-1)(-x) \\
(-y)(-2) + (2x+y)(-1)
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\frac{1}{2(x^2-2xy-y^2)}
\begin{pmatrix}
4y - x \\
y - 2x
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: You are brilliant Sir. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much